# Are .pdf always vector images?

Tags: image, pdf, vector

If I'm receiving an asset in .pdf format, does it *mean* it'll be vectorial?

I'm under the assumption that no, but I've been told yes. Nothing proves the guy didnt just put a .png image in a pdf, that does not make it vectorial.

My reasoning is that I could save a picture of my cat as a .pdf, it does not make it vector-friendly. So why would the asset be?

Following that reasoning, the designer could've `Saved as .pdf` but that does not mean the design is vectorial, it's still a basic design that'll be ruined by any kind of resizing.

Comment: Please anyone who speaks better english than I do, feel free to edit the word "vectorial" if it's not correct.

Comment: Use the `pdfimages` tool in the **Poppler** package to see exactly what images are embedded and extract them.

Comment: You already have the correct idea that calling a PDF showing merely an embedded bitmap "vectorial" is not sensible. But what do you expect as an answer? Simple support like in Orel's answer? Or something with references to be more convincing?

Answer (score 1):

PDF isn't a vector per se, but it can be.
It depends on the image stored inside the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

PDF files can contain any combination of image, vector, and font drawing instructions but additionally can contain sound files, 3D models, and video.